# Why is my razor view complaining "} expected" after upgrade to razor 2 / mvc 4?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an existing razor 1 / mvc 3 view, with a few nested `if` - very simple, but after upgrading to razor 2 / mvc 4 it is complaining at runtime and compile (`BuildViews`) about `} expected`. It used to work fine.

- I've checked all the elements are well-formed / closed
- I've checked that all the `{` / `}` are balanced - this isn't the end-of-file issue

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A number of legacy razor oddities were fixed in the razor 2 / mvc 4 upgrade; one interesting gotcha is that in razor 1, the following is legal (in a code region):

```
string foo = @Some.Complex.Expression;
```

Note that the `@` there is superfluous and incorrect, but that razor 1 does not complain. However, razor 2 is more fussy and gets confused, reporting the `} expected` error. This line should be replaced with:

```
string foo = Some.Complex.Expression;
```

This is a bit subtle, because the error that occurs has *nothing* to do with braces (`{`/`}`), and can be some lines away from the reported line.

Comment: THANK YOU.  This totally saved my day.  The same problem occurs if you do `var @class = "something";`

Comment: Inherited some old code and this saved my butt.

Too bad VS2013 can't show you where this error is really occurring in your cshtml files.