# Using a Ternary in a @using Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

All,

I am trying to implement a ternary with a @using statement, in order to switch out the `@enctype` for certain cases, defined in my ternary. I am getting a Razor parse error stating that I am missing a closing "}" in my `@using` statement. This error is misleading because all of my curly braces match up fine. I am including the entire form since I cannot see any obvious issues with the syntax in the ternary section.

It looks like the issue is the if/else block but not sure why......

Any ideas why this is problematic? A better way?

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("ProcessCompose", 
                      "ClubOpeningTool",
                      FormMethod.Post,
                      new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "update_panel" },
                      new { enctype = (fileAttachmentUnsupported ?  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" : "multipart/form-data"), 
                      id = "ComposeForm" }))
{

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     <fieldset style="width:90%">
         <p class="required"><strong>* Required</strong></p>
         <div id="update_panel"></div>
         <div>
             <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; color:#000000;">To:</span>
         </div>
         <div>
             <table id="compose" class="table-grid">
                 <tr>
                     <td><strong>Available @(isTeam? "Team Mambers": Model.Mode)</strong> <br />
                         @Html.ListBox("AvaliableRecipients", Model.AvailabeRecipients, new{@class="ncb-listbox"})
                     </td>
                     <td><button id="addAllRecipient" type="button">>></button><br /><button id="addRecipient" type="button">> </button><br /><button id="removeRecipient" type="button">< </button><br /><button id="removeAllRecipient" type="button"><<</button>
                         <script type="text/javascript">
                             $(function () {
                                 $('#addRecipient').click(function () {
                                     $('#AvaliableRecipients option:selected').appendTo('#Recipients');

                                 });
                                 $('#addAllRecipient').click(function () {
                                     $('#AvaliableRecipients option').appendTo('#Recipients');
                                     $("#Recipients option").attr("selected", "selected");

                                 });

                                 $('#removeRecipient').click(function () {
                                     $('#Recipients option:selected').appendTo('#AvaliableRecipients');
                                 });

                                 $('#removeAllRecipient').click(function () {
                                     $('#Recipients option').appendTo('#AvaliableRecipients');
                                 });

                             });

                             $("form").submit(function () {
                                 $('#Recipients').find("option").attr('selected', 'true');
                             });
                         </script>
                     </td>
                     <td><strong>Current Recipients</strong>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span><br />
                         @Html.ListBox("Recipients", Model.Recipients,new{@class="ncb-listbox"})<br /><span class="messageBottom">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Recipients)</span>
                     </td>
                 </tr>

             </table>

         </div>

         <div>
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subject) &nbsp;<span class="required">*</span>
         </div>
         <div>
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subject)<br />
             <span class="messageBottom">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject)</span>
         </div>
        @if (!fileAttachmentUnsupported)
        {
            <div>
                <label>
                    File Attachment @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FileName)
                </label> <i>(9MB file size limit)</i>

            </div>

            <input class="js-file-text" type="text" id="fileUploadFileName" name="fileUploadFileName">

            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FileAttachment, new {type = "file", @class = "js-file-field"})
            <a class="btn blue js-file-btn">Browse</a>
        }
        else
        {
              <div>
                <label>
                    <b>Attachment feature not available for Internet Explorer 10 (IE10 or earlier)</b>
                </label> 
              </div>
        }


         @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmailID)
         @Html.HiddenFor(model =>model.NewClubId)
         @Html.HiddenFor(model =>model.Mode)
         @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DraftOrSentViewMode)
         <div>
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Body)&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span>
         </div>
         <div>
             @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body)<br />
             <span class="messageBottom">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body)</span>
         </div>


         <p>
             <input type="submit" id="btnComposeSend" name="Command" value="Send" class="btn blue saveSend"/>
             @if (! isTeam) {
                <input id="btnComposeSave" type="submit" name="Command" value="Save" class="btn blue saveSend"/>
             }
         </p>
     </fieldset>


}
```

Comment: This might simply mean you don't need the `@`. Try it without the `@` - in particular, in `@enctype`; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12317656/23354 for more information

Comment: I'd at least suggest refactoring the code... Maybe into a method in regular code somewhere? 370-character-long lines don't make for easy reading.

Comment: An [HTML helper](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/N50P050314-Understanding-HTML-Helpers-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html) would be appropriate here; it'd let you refactor this into a call to that helper.

Comment: Removing the @ from enctype has no effect but it was a good idea

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why this isn't working, maybe post the whole view? Having said that, if it was me, I would try this...

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm(
        "ProcessCompose", 
        "ClubOpeningTool",
         FormMethod.Post,
         new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "update_panel" },
         new { @enctype = (fileAttachmentUnsupported ?  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" : "multipart/form-data"), id = "ComposeForm" }))
{ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks much but still getting the same parse error, stating that my @using is missing a closing "}" I pasted the entire form just in case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was being caused by an unclosed input tag in the if/else block. Not sure why intellisense did not pick this up or why the error message was seemingly unrelated to the actual problem. Thanks everyone

**Before**

```
 <input class="js-file-text" type="text" id="fileUploadFileName" name="fileUploadFileName">
```

**After**

```
 <input class="js-file-text" type="text" id="fileUploadFileName" name="fileUploadFileName" />
```